# Switching between two framebuffer programs

Tags: linux, debian, shell, terminal, framebuffer

I have two programs (mplayer and a custom java application) which both present GUI using framebuffers. They run in separate processes. I want to be able to switch from one program to the other without ending/killing the process of the other(the reason is that launching the java program takes a lot of time).
I want to simulate sending one of the two programs to background and hiding its GUI and showing the other program's gui.

I am running this on a Raspberry Pi, Debian distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to pause the programs with ctrl+z and then use `fg` to resume them? I do not have a framebuffer setup so I can not test.

For example:

1. start `mplayer`, press ctrl+z
2. start the java program, press ctrl+z
3. run `jobs` to the see list of paused programs
4. run `fg %2` to resume the java program, press ctrl+z to pause it again

If this works, you can also use `bg` to resume the programs in the background.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html